# Actual code of row and column widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for the actual code of the row and column widgets in flutter.  I can't find it though.  Does anyone know where this is located and what language it is in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most of Flutter, `Column` and `Row` are both widgets implemented in Dart. The source code for both Column and Row is here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart